Fastendpoints with Get method and query string parameter in Swagger
When I am using Fastendpoint with Get method and query string parameters swagger document does not seem to be created correctly, it just shows as a part of the body which will cause and error if I supply the query string values in the body, any ideas?
It would be appreciated if you can provide sample code working with Swagger in both with Request object and without Request object
When I have a request object it allows me to put the properties of the request object but it fails with "reason": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')"

When I have a request object it allows me to put the properties of the request object but it fails with  "reason": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')"

correct swagger documentation requires a request dto to be present when query paramas are involved. here's the reason.

Can you provide the code in your program.cs where you are configuring FastEndpoints for Swagger. Also please provide the code for your endpoint.

forgot to mention, when you do have a request dto and some of the properties are to be bound from query params, you need to annote those properties with the [Queryparam] attribute as explained in the docs. only then will swagger know to convert those properties to query params.

I do not think we will need  any attribute for requests dto's properties to bound them to query string values, FastEndpoints will do it for us without any configuration

documentation says the following: The [QueryParam] attribute does not affect model binding in any way. It is simply an instruction for Swagger to add a query param for the operation.

I had this same issue and the reason for failure was because I was missing the [QueryParam] attribute from the request property.

I create an api project using vs 2022 template, installing the following nuget packages:
<PackageReference Include="FastEndpoints" Version="5.28.0" />
<PackageReference Include="FastEndpoints.Swagger" Version="5.28.0" />

and here's my Program.cs
using FastEndpoints;
using FastEndpoints.Swagger;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddFastEndpoints();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
//builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.SwaggerDocument();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseFastEndpoints();
app.UseSwaggerGen();
app.Run();

And this is my test sample:
using FastEndpoints;

namespace WebApi.Features.SignUp
{

    public class Endpoint : Endpoint<Request, Response>
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Post("/signup");
            AllowAnonymous();
        }

        public override async Task HandleAsync(Request r, CancellationToken c)
        {
            await SendAsync(new Response()
            {
                Message = $"hello {r.FirstName} {r.LastName}! your request has been received!"
            });
        }
    }

    public class GetArticle : EndpointWithoutRequest<Response>
    {
        public override void Configure() {
            Get("/article/{ArticleID}");
            AllowAnonymous();
        } 

        public override async Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            //http://localhost:5000/article/123
            int articleID = Route<int>("ArticleID");
            await SendAsync(new Response()
            {
                Message = $"hello {articleID}"
            });
        }
    }

    public class GetArticle2 : Endpoint<Article, Response>
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Get("/article/{ArticleId}/{ArticleName}");
            AllowAnonymous();
        }

        public override async Task HandleAsync(Article r, CancellationToken c)
        {
            await SendAsync(new Response()
            {
                Message = $"hello {r.ArticleId} {r.ArticleName}! "
            });
        }
    }

    public class GetArticle3 : EndpointWithoutRequest<Response>
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Get("/article");
            AllowAnonymous();
        }

        public override async Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            //http://localhost:5000/article?id=123&name=artileA
            string articleID = Route<int>("id", isRequired: false) == 0? "": Route<int>("id", isRequired: false).ToString();
            string articleName = Route<string>("name", isRequired: false);
            await SendAsync(new Response()
            {
                Message = $"hello {articleID} {articleName}"
            });
        }
    }

    public class Article {
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }
        public string ArticleName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}

All of above worked well, except the api defined in public class GetArticle : EndpointWithoutRequest<Response>. When I test in swagger I will get 400 error  like below. It looks like Swagger didn't read the article Id I set in UI which causing the request doesn't have an id inside the endpoint.

But since it's a get request, if I hit https://localhost:7043/article/123， it could worked well.

So that I I recommend defining an DTO for the query parameters just like what I did in public class GetArticle2 : Endpoint<Article, Response>. This worked well.

Or we can try codes below instead of GetArticle3
public class GetArticle4 : Endpoint<Article,Response>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Get("/article");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(Article a, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        //http://localhost:5000/article?id=123&name=artileA
        string articleID = Route<int>("id", isRequired: false) == 0 ? "" : Route<int>("id", isRequired: false).ToString();
        string articleName = Route<string>("name", isRequired: false);
        int id = a.ArticleId;
        string name = a.ArticleName;
        await SendAsync(new Response()
        {
            Message = $"hello {articleID} {articleName}"
        });
    }
}


I presume you are trying to retrieve your request from Route instead of query string, When you are using query string you will not be able to use query string template in your route something like "?articleId={articleId}&articleName={articleName}"

@GholamrezaFathpour I might make a mistake to understand query string. Could you pls show me a sample for query string?

Query string will show up in the get method with the following template /ListItems?pageSize=10&currentPage=3  which is a common way to filter data and route will be different as with the routing we are targeting a resource with its identifier for example /items/4 which specifiy item with identifier = 4 hope it is clear

pls see my GetArticle3 and GetArticle4.....   https://i.sstatic.net/rUGFptgk.png

Thanks @Tiny Wang, for sharing your snapshots, when you have a request with query string it is all good and you can use Query instead of Route to fetch the data from query string and swagger will generate UI for it, there problem arise when there is not request with Query String

Hi @GholamrezaFathpour , do you mean make the parameter optional? https://i.sstatic.net/cw0KlTKg.png

HI @TinyWang, not really, have seen we do not really need to have a request object when we are using the query string and as long as you have the query string params in the URL you can retrieve them with Query as you have done with Route

sorry, I can't understand your requirement well....
